# Google search: Is it possible to search sites by value of tag attribute?

Tags: google, google-dorks

Is it possible to search sites by value of HTML tag attribute?

I'm looking for something like this:
`intext: <meta version="SomeCMS 3.2.6"/>`

But in this case `intext` doesn't works.

Comment: Probably because there's not supposed to be a space between the filter operator and the value. Try your query in quotation marks, google will only show pages with literally that string.

Comment: No, you can't search for HTML tags unless they are displayed literally. I can see why you're asking this on SecSE but it's really no security topic.